# Not receiving SMS sent from SMS-Gateway in Java?

Tags: java, sms, sms-gateway

FreeSMS issue again !

I am using http://www.freesmsgateway.com/api to send SMS on mobile through Java.

I have registered on the given portal, I got the api-key. Using this api-key, when I run the Java code I get the following response -

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/api_send.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 127</p>

</div>Message sent
```

But I am not receiving any SMS on mobile. Also I have tried to send SMS from their website but didn't received any SMS.

My Java Code -

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.FreeSMSGateway.com/api_send");
String access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
String message = "Hello, this is demo message from SMS gateway";
String send_to = "post_contacts";
JSONArray jPostContact = new JSONArray();
jPostContact.put("+91XXXXXXXXXX");
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", access_token));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("send_to", send_to));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_contacts", jPostContact.toString()));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: This is clearly a server problem on their end. Improper validation I'd say. There code is lacking somwhere if they show you the exact php error

Comment: Ohh, I am not understanding what should I do now? Is there any other free gateway for SMS?

Comment: are you passing all the parameters you need to. Most probably that's the reason. Its not able to handle a non passed parameter. Make sure you'er passing all the required parametrs

Comment: Yes I am passing all the required parameters. "access_token, message, send_to and post_contacts" these are required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "content-type" to "application/json" and you will get rid of this problem

Comment: I have already tried this, but its not worked.
BTW the issue is might be from their server side bcoz I have also tried the same PHP code from their example which was also not running. So I moved to other gateway.